# Is NEXT_PUBLIC_.... similar to REACT_APP_....?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

Sometimes I want to hide url link while using GET or POST method. Whenever I used react app I would hide the url using REACT_APP_. My question is, if I am using a Next.js APP, could I use NEXT_PUBLIC_URL instead? Does both of these variable work similarly? How are they different?

**React APP**

```
axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_URL)
```

**Next APP**

```
axios.get(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your react app runs on the client so there is no way to securely keep variables there.

From the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!
> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.

The documentation makes it clear by referencing it as:

```
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE
```

When you are doing `process.env.REACT_APP_URL` above you are not hiding anything. You requests could well be seen in Chrome Dev Tools.

[Environment variables](https://medium.com/chingu/an-introduction-to-environment-variables-and-how-to-use-them-f602f66d15fa) here can help in having different values of the URL for different environments eg: `staging-api/dev-api/prod-api`. Not for securing API keys or secrets.

Coming to your question are the two same - Yes, `NEXT_PUBLIC_` is a good counter part to the react `REACT_APP_`. It also [exposes variables to the browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) and can be used for such routes etc.

Next.JS, since it runs on the server side too, gives you a way to secure your variables and not expose the browser. That is by omitting the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` (so basically using the naming convention for any generic environment variable).

From the docs:

> By default environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.